# Why doesn't my simple echo command not work?

Tags: linux

I just gave a simple `echo` command on centos 7 command line:

```
echo "what is the worst thing someone has said to you about cloth diaper ? ( hopefully nothing ) here's mine !! :..."
```

It threw an error:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can someone please elaborate?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on the unix/linux stackexchange

Comment: Work for me on `zsh` and`bash`

Comment: Same here, works just fine.

Comment: Using single quotes will remove the special meaning of some characters such as `!`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

double quotes allows shell to expand variables, for example `!!` has a special meaning.  If you want to treat everything as text, use single quotes instead.

For example;

```
$ date
Thu Oct  6 11:14:59 EDT 2016

$ echo "!!"
echo "date"
date

$ echo '!!'
!!
```